# Why this macro accepts a template with 1 parameter and refuses a template with 2 parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, cppunit

I'm working with CPPUNIT 1.12.1.

It has those macro defined:

```
#define CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_ADD_TEST( test ) \
      context.addTest( test )

#define CPPUNIT_TEST( testMethod )                        \
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_ADD_TEST(                           \
        ( new CPPUNIT_NS::TestCaller<TestFixtureType>(    \
                  context.getTestNameFor( #testMethod),   \
                  &TestFixtureType::testMethod,           \
                  context.makeFixture() ) ) )
```

I want to add many tests to the same test suite using templates (as CPPUNIT works, every test must be a `void` function, so using template makes it possible to call the same `void` function with different "parameters"...).

This works perfectly:

```
class MyTestSuite1 : public CPPUNIT_NS::TestFixture
{
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(MyTestSuite1);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(doTest<false>);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(doTest<true>);
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

    template<bool param> void doTest() { /* test here */ }
};
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(MyTestSuite1);
```

while this does not:

```
class MyTestSuite2 : public CPPUNIT_NS::TestFixture
{
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(MyTestSuite2);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(doTest<false,false>);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(doTest<true,false>);
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

    template<bool param1,bool param2> void doTest() { /* test here */ }
};
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(MyTestSuite2);
```

Compiler (Visual Studio 2015) reports:

> 1>b:\dev\vobs_diabeloop\private\tst\regulation\cppunit\hyper_ftac3\test.cpp(20):
>   warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'CPPUNIT_TEST'
>   1>b:\dev\vobs_diabeloop\private\tst\regulation\cppunit\hyper_ftac3\test.cpp(21):
>   warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'CPPUNIT_TEST'
>   1>b:\dev\vobs_diabeloop\private\tst\regulation\cppunit\hyper_ftac3\test.cpp(20):
>   error C2059: syntax error: ')'
>   1>b:\dev\vobs_diabeloop\private\tst\regulation\cppunit\hyper_ftac3\test.cpp(21):
>   error C2059: syntax error: ')'
>   1>b:\dev\vobs_diabeloop\private\tst\regulation\cppunit\hyper_ftac3\test.cpp(22):
>   error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
>   1>b:\dev\vobs_diabeloop\private\tst\regulation\cppunit\hyper_ftac3\test.cpp(22):
>   error C2065: 'namer': undeclared identifier
>   1>b:\dev\vobs_diabeloop\private\tst\regulation\cppunit\hyper_ftac3\test.cpp(22):
>   error C2065: 'factory': undeclared identifier
>   1>b:\dev\vobs_diabeloop\private\tst\regulation\cppunit\hyper_ftac3\test.cpp(22):
>   error C2059: syntax error: ')'
>   1>b:\dev\vobs_diabeloop\private\tst\regulation\cppunit\hyper_ftac3\test.cpp(29):
>   error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
>   1>b:\dev\vobs_diabeloop\private\tst\regulation\cppunit\hyper_ftac3\test.cpp(30):
>   error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'

Why is that? How could the macro handle correctly 1 template parameter, but fails for two? Any idea how I could easily have it compile and work?

Edit:
Already tried `CPPUNIT_TEST((doTest<false,false>));` without success (getting `error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ')'`)

Comment: `#define COMMA ,` then `CPPUNIT_TEST(doTest<false COMMA false>);`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: Incredible...it works. But I'm really curious to understand why....could you post this as an answer with more explanation?

Comment: `CPPUNIT_TEST((doTest<false,false>));` -> `&TestFixtureType::(doTest<false,false>)` is invalid. Preprocessor think `CPPUNIT_TEST(doTest<false COMMA false>);` has 1 parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CPPUNIT_TEST(doTest<false,false>);
```

This one doesn't work because macro thinks you are passing 2 macro parameters: `doTest<false` and `false>`.

---

```
CPPUNIT_TEST((doTest<false,false>));
```

This doesn't work because `&TestFixtureType::testMethod` will expand to `&TestFixtureType::(doTest<false,false>)` which is invalid.

---

As mentioned by Piotr in comment, you can use this code:

```
#define COMMA ,
class MyTestSuite2 : public CPPUNIT_NS::TestFixture
{
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(MyTestSuite2);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(doTest<false COMMA false>);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(doTest<true COMMA  false>);
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

    template<bool param1, bool param2> void doTest() { /* test here */ }
};
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(MyTestSuite2);
```

Because pre-processor sees that you want to pass 1 parameter

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks Danh.

Answer (score 1):

`,` is parsed as separator in MACRO (except when surrounded by parent).

way of work-around

using intermediate MACRO:

```
#define COMMA ,

CPPUNIT_TEST(doTest<false COMMA false>);
```

Or fix your original MACRO to handle comma:

```
#define CPPUNIT_TEST(testMethod, ...)                           \
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_ADD_TEST(                                \
        ( new CPPUNIT_NS::TestCaller<TestFixtureType>(          \
                  context.getTestNameFor( #testMethod),         \
                  &TestFixtureType::testMethod , ##__VA_ARGS__, \
                  context.makeFixture() ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
CPPUNIT_TEST((doTest<false,false>));
CPPUNIT_TEST((doTest<true,false>));
```

sometimes Macros can be tricky when parsing commas...

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that in my post. Already tried without success.