# What are examples of test suite property uses in CPPUnit? (CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_PROPERTY)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cppunit

I joined a project where CPPUnit is used for unit testing and will be adding some tests that probably share setup and teardown code.  In researching this more I came across

```
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_PROPERTY
```

(from https://people.freedesktop.org/~mmohrhard/cppunit/group___writing_test_fixture.html)

Its description says

> Adds a property to the test suite builder context.

http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/group___writing_test_fixture.html says the following:

> Adds a property to the test suite builder context

I am not sure what the expected use or purpose of that would be, though it ***appears*** like it could be useful for sharing common information, etc.  I don't see examples of its use.

**What is the value of this and are there some examples to point me to?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this piece of code](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/_xml_input_helper_8h.html#a0), it looks like you should be able to retrieve the property at some point while you are creating your test suite to pass it as a parameter to a specific test.

Maybe the goal was to allow you to do:

```
#define CPPUNIT_TEST_WITH_PARAM(testMethod,param) \
    CPPUNIT_TEST_ADD( new CppUnit::ParameterizedTestCase<ThisTestFixtureType>( \
                                        context.getTestNameFor( #testMethod ), \
                                        #testMethod, \
                                        &TestFixtureType::testMethod, \
                                        context.makeFixture(), \
                                        context.getStringProperty( param ) ) )

CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE( MyTestSuite);
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_PROPERTY( "param1", "foo" )
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_PROPERTY( "param2", "bar" )
CPPUNIT_CPPUNIT_TEST_WITH_PARAM( func, "param1" )
CPPUNIT_CPPUNIT_TEST_WITH_PARAM( func, "param2" )
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

void func( const std::string& param );
```

And this would have ended calling `func("foo")` and `func("bar")`. Which would be nice because it would have made it possible to add string parametrized tests.

However, and **this is just a guess attempt**, as `ParameterizedTestCase` is not part of 1.12.1 old release, nor is it part of more [recent releases](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/cppunit/) (so does `CPPUNIT_TEST_ADD` macro), I believe this is apparently something that was in a release plan but aborted and the macro `CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_PROPERTY` remains useless here. The `getStringProperty` also remains, and I found no way it could be used properly.

To conclude, this looks like a broken stuff and was anyway apparently not meant to share setup/teardown code, but more to have parametrized tests (which can be done by templates actually, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41566342/3336423)).